# FTP via shellscript

Tags: bash, shell, ftp

I want to upload a file using a shellscript. I know scp is the better way to solve such a task, but I need to use FTP. This is what I got:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST='myServer'
USER='anonymous'
PASSWD=''
DIR = '/Public'

ftp -n -v $HOST << EOT
user $USER $PASSWD
prompt
cd $MYDIRECTORY
mput cam.jpg
bye
EOT
```

The directory **Public** is accessible with the anonymous user. I'll get this response:

> Connected to myServer.
>   220 Some text
>   331 Anonymous login ok, send your 
>   complete email address as your password

There is still a prompt for a username. I don't get this and I don't see the error... Thank You for any advice

Comment: It's not clear if you tried "send your complete email address as your password" per the status msg. Consider updating your Q with this important info ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: SInce `$PASSWD` is empty, you're just sending the username without a password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, at least this should work but I think there is a much better solution to your issue.

Try

```
PASSWD='\n'
```

This should "work" and solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous login requires a password, but you're trying to send an empty password. Change it to:

```
PASSWD=user@yourdomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions: Make sure you can interactively log in with 'anonymous' id and it works

Another thing I noticed, you should remove the space before and after the equal sign. Otherwise bash will say 'line 5: DIR: command not found'

```
DIR = '/Public'
```

Also, it is not clear that $MYDIRECTORY is already defined the environment.  It is not in the script.